# Where can I find the zipped Stock/Default Prestashop modules?

Tags: module, prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.7

I use **Prestashop** versions **1.6** and **1.7.**
Sometimes I need to reinstall the modules from the **admin panel**. For re-installation from the admin panel, the zip files of the modules are required. 
Where can I find the **zipped** Stock/Default Prestashop modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official repository for native PrestaShop modules is available on Github at:
https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop-modules

You can easily download each of them as a zip file on Github via the "Clone or Download" button:
[image: Github]

Alternately, you can also create an account on [PrestaShop Addons](https://addons.prestashop.com) to download partner modules for free (you won't be able to download core modules on this website).

Comment: Yes, there are modules here! But the modules here are suitable for the current version of Prestashop. How do I find module commits that support Prestashop 1.6 or older versions?

Comment: Most of these are compatible for both versions (if not, Github allows you to download older files, same for PrestaShop Addons), when you open the main module file, you can verify this by looking at this line in `__construct()`: `$this->ps_versions_compliancy = [
            'min' => '1.6.0.0',
            'max' => _PS_VERSION_,
        ];`